# Сохранение текста поля entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Я создаю приложение, [Remote Controller](https://github.com/Johnny-kiv/Remote-controller), которое будет включать фильмы с помощью telegram bot. У меня все готово кроме интерфейса. Я делаю интерфейс на tkinter. Вот мой код интерфейса:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os

def show_message():
    config = open("config.py","w")
    tokenT = token.get()
    adminT = admin.get()
    if (tokenT=='' and adminT=='') or (tokenT=='' or adminT==''):
        print("Поля пустые!")
    else:
        config.write(f"bot_token = '{tokenT}'" + "\n")
        config.write(f"admin = '{adminT}'")
        config.close()
        os.system("./main.py")

root = Tk()
root.title("Remote controller")
root.geometry("250x150")
tokenL = Label(text="Введите токен вашего бота:")
tokenL.pack()
token = ttk.Entry()
token.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)
adminL = Label(text="Введите ваш id:")
adminL.pack()
admin = ttk.Entry()
admin.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=7)

btn = ttk.Button(text="Запуск бота", command=show_message)
btn.pack(anchor=NW, padx=6, pady=6)
root.mainloop()
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтоб в полях token и admin при перезапуске сохранялись в приложении?

Comment: Думаю можно попробовать реализовать сохранение с текстовом документе и уже последующее изъятие из него.

Comment: а вообще, на сколько мне известно токен нужно беречь как зеницу ока. и странно что его необходимо вносить в какое-либо поле

Comment: Я пытался так делать, но проблема в том как изъять из него

Comment: Я сохраняю токен чтоб пользователь, мог вставить свой токен и запускать свой бот

Comment: Попробуйте почитать про configparser, библиотека в которой реализован механизм работы с текстовыми файлами для таких дел.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую